# How can I get the .exe name using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, pyinstaller

I have multiple Python scripts and I formed an .exe using pyinstaller.
How do i  get the name of the exe?

I tried

```py
file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(file_path)

exename = os.path.basename(__file__)
print(exename)

USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()
bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
print(bat_path)

with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
    bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```

and it's writing this on the .bat file:

```
start "" C:\Users\sg\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI235882
```

Is this correct? When I tried running this on the terminal I got an error, I was expecting

```
start "" C:\Users\sg\AppData\Local\Temp\<my executable name>
```

This looks different

Comment: How should we know? we do not see your executable. Anyway, you are missing the extension of the file name…

Comment: Have you read this? https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#:~:text=for%20these%20uses.-,Using%20__file__,relative%20to%20the%20bundle%20folder. or this https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__file__` to get the name of the current file. When used in the main module, this is the name of the script that was originally invoked.

If you want to omit the directory part (which might be present), you can use `os.path.basename(__file__)`.